# Input filtering in PHP

Tags: php, security, filtering

I am filtering user input in this way

```
$id= intval($_REQUEST['id']);
```

I am accepting only integers in `$id`.

Is there anything else which i can use to make it more secure?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with 'id' afterwards? Putting it an database?

Comment: Be aware that `$_REQUEST` is the union of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and `$_COOKIE`. You can’t say where that value originated from.

Comment: `$id= intval($_REQUEST['id']);`. It isn't validation. It's filter)

Comment: It's sufficient for input cleaning.

Comment: i am using id to get data from database.

Comment: is it velnerable to sql injection,XSS,or RFI ?

Comment: @Mohammad Adil: From the information you’ve provided, you’re not doing anything with that value except assigning it to `$id`.

Comment: @Gumbo: $query = "select * from news where id = $id ";

Comment: You should tell your user that he did something wrong, because intval() modifies his input without him knowing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a sufficiently recent PHP version, you can use the [filter extension](http://php.net/filter) to validate your input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
<?php
$var = filter_var('0755', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
?>
```

The nifty thing is that you can do more complex validation like that (min lenght, default value etc.), check php.net's filter_var page.

Answer (score 0):

Just to re-iterate your question:

> I am filtering user input in this way
>   $id= intval($_REQUEST['id']);
>   I am accepting only integers in $id.
>   Is there anything else which i can use to make it more secure?

I think you could just do a filter True : False by using ctype_digit($id);

You are accepting only integers in $id, What is a Integer: An integer is a number that can be written without a fractional or decimal component. For example, 21, 4, and −2048 are integers; 9.75, 5½, and √2 are not integers. The set of integers is a subset of the real numbers, and consists of the natural number (1, 2, 3, ...), zero (0) and the negatives of the natural numbers (−1, −2, −3, ...). > Taken form Wikipedia